# Error while starting the business network using hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

@Paul O'Mahony:I am using composer version v0.19.14 on a Mac. When I try to start the business network, I get the following error : 
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed.

I have checked the peer logs and the errors that I found are :

1.Error:not_found,  Status Code:404,  Reason:Database does not exist.

2.Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp :5984: getsockopt: connection refused

3.stopping due to error while launching: timeout expired while starting chaincode clp-network:0.0.1(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com

I did not find any npm errors in the log.

Comment: Have you tried disabling (or configuring) your firewall, I assume its enabled - looks like it may be preventing access on the port. If not that, have you tried the dns_search option as described [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2218#issuecomment-331759596) - a setting in the Yaml file. Could be you've got a resolution issue for 'couchdb' : have you tried to put the ip address / hostname combo in your hosts file and starting it/the peer again using the YAML file?  Have seen weird routing issues on Mac causing similar issues.

Comment: The clue is in the message:  'connection refused' (as you wrote previously on RC, the couchDB container starts ok).

Comment: @Paul O'Mahony: Thanks for the reply. I tried the dns_search option, but it didnt help. Regarding "put the ip address / hostname combo in your hosts file and starting it/the peer again using the YAML file" , do I need to add couchdb container ip and hostname as http://couchdb? Also, regarding the firewall, yes it is enabled. If I need get the destination ip and the port opened on the firewall, the port is 5984, what would be the ip? As I see that the ip changes everytime I start the Fabric